# Self join in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting the following exception as :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: expecting OPEN, found '.' near line 1, column 35 [from in.bets.crm.model.User u1, in.bets.crm.model.User u2 where u1.manager is not null and u2.manager.id = u1.id];
nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found '.' near line 1, column 35 [from in.bets.crm.model.User u1, in.bets.crm.model.User u2 where u1.manager is not null and u2.manager.id = u1.id]
```

I have written the query like :

```
users=hibernateTemplate.find("from User u1, User u2 where u1.manager is not null and u2.manager.id = u1.id");
```

Please help in resolving this error.
Thanks

Comment: Column 35 is the dot in `u1.manager`. Does User have an property called manager?

Comment: Please add the code of your User class to the question.

Comment: I think it is the dot in the second "in.bets". There is not much sens in selecting from two tables in HQL. Should probably be a "from User u1 join u1.manager (...)", but it depends on the implementation of the User bean.

Answer (score 0):

## try this: (just added select and join keywords! )

users=hibernateTemplate.find("select u from User u inner join User m where u.manager is not null and u.manager.id = m.id");